# Long-running batch process being terminated prematurely in Ubuntu

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, keras

I'm trying to batch some python scripts that train deep neural networks using Keras and I'm encountering the problem that when the first python script finishes, the whole batch is stopped.

I tried writing a python wrapper, but still nothing changes. I wonder if this problem is OS related or it has to do with Keras framework or python.

The first attempt was to write a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {1..10}; do python my_experiment.py; done
```

However, after running `my_experiment.py` once, the whole batch stops.

I tried using Python:

```
import subprocess
import os

def main():
    for i in xrange(10):
        subprocess.call(['python', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'my_experiment.py')])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I still get the same result.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? If not I would welcome ideas to try and figure out what's going on.

Additionally, I'm running this process in a remote machine via SSH, in the following way:

```
$ ./batch_script.sh &
$ disown
```

Or in the case of python:

```
$ python batch_script.py &
$ disown
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This might happen if some processes still have standard input or output linked to the tty, or if some sub-processes are not properly disowned.

A possible workaround is to use a terminal multiplexer such as [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.github.io) to solve the problem of leaving a background process running after an SSH logout. It is much easier to use than disowning / nohuping a process.

Typically you will run `screen` or `tmux`, and you will get a new terminal session. You will be able to 'detach' from that session and leave it running. After you log out and log in again, you will be able to 'reattach' to the running sessions and see the output of the process as if you never logged out.

Comment: Just for clarification, the first run of the python script runs until the end and finishes successfully. Is in that moment when the next batched instance doesn't start.

You raise a good point which is the output to tty though. I will explore that.

Comment: Maybe the second process wants to write something to stdout? Try redirecting explicitly stdout/stderr when you start your batch? `$ ./batch_script.sh &> output.log &`

Comment: That's exactly what I did :) I'll update with my findings, thanks